# SEO: Can dynamically generated links be crawled?

Tags: seo, web-crawler, dynamic-linking, google-crawlers

I have a page containing `<div>` tags with onclick="" code that calls an ajax request to get json data, and then iterates through the results to form links (`<a />`) to append to the page. These links do not exist in any other place on my website. How can I make these dynamically generated links crawlable?

My initial thought was to turn the `<div>` tags into `<a>` tags with a href="#", but with my limited knowledge of how typical crawlers work, i don't think this would solve my problem since the "#" would be what's recognized by the crawler, and not necessarily the dynamically generated output. This is besides the point that i don't want the scroll positioning to be altered at all, which would also rule out giving the `<a>` tag an id and having it reference itself.

Do I have any options aside from making a new page containing all of the links i need to be crawled? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, content that is created or made available through JavaScript cannot be found or indexed by search engines. Google does support [crawlable Ajax](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html) but using it as the only means of accessing your content is bad for accessibility. Also, other search engines can't get to that content which is also not a good thing. Basically [crawable ajax is a bad thing](http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/).

You should always make your content available without requiring JavaScript to get it. Then you can improve your site by adding JavaScript to make getting the content faster or easier. This is called [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and is how good websites are built.